# создание списков введёных слов

Tags: golang

Пользователь программы вводит строку, а программа составляет список слов.

К примеру : "Привет мир, hello world, hello мир, привет world"

на выходе должен получится список список :

```
привет - 2;
мир - 2;
hello - 2;
world -2;
```

как написать такую функцию?

Comment: Нет такой функции, придется писать её самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать как-то так, но надо учитывать что тут все буквы приводятся к нижнему регистру, иначе слова Привет и привет будут считаться разными словами.
ps: проверка
`if regexp.MustCompile("[a-zа-яё]+").MatchString(arr[i])`
нужна для того чтобы в результаты не пролез мусор в виде пробелов если пользователь введёт что-то типа

```
"Привет мир, hello world, hello мир, привет world,   , "
```

хотя это можно сделать и красивее

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

//Создаём структуру для хранения кол-ва слов и самих слов
type Words struct {
    i int    // кол-во слов
    s string // тут само слово
}

func main() {
    str := "Привет мир, hello world, hello мир, привет world,   , "
    // приводим всё в нижний регистр для устранения проблем с различием слов 'Привет' и 'привет'
    str = strings.ToLower(str)
    // Разбиваем строку на массив строк по регулярному выражению, ищем либо ',' либо ' ' (пробел)
    arr := regexp.MustCompile("[,| ]+").Split(str, -1)
    //создаём массив структур для хранения результатов
    ret := []Words{}
    chk := false
    // проходим циклом для сранения есть ли такое слово в массиве ret или нет
    k := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        chk = false
        for k = 0; k < len(ret); k++ {
            if arr[i] == ret[k].s {
                // если слово уже есть увеличивем счётчик и слово пропускаем
                ret[k].i += 1
                chk = true
            }
        }
        // если chk true то слово уже есть и ничего делать ненадо
        if !chk {
            // проверяем что в строке есть буквы и если они есть добавляем её в массив с результатами
            if regexp.MustCompile("[a-zа-яё]+").MatchString(arr[i]) {
                tmp := Words{i: 1, s: arr[i]}
                ret = append(ret, tmp)
            }

        }
    }
    // выводим результат
    for l := 0; l < len(ret); l++ {
        fmt.Printf("%v - %v\n", (ret[l].s), (ret[l].i))
    }

}
```